# How to build a form without using tables in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, forms

i need a three columns form, in the past using tables was easy but now using divs i dont know from where to start... im googling but the css i found doesnt work for me, any help or link will be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a sample row  which shows one of the ways u can do this.

```
<div>
<span style="width:33%;display:inline-block"></span>
<span style="width:33%;display:inline-block"></span>
<span style="width:33%;display:inline-block"></span>
</div>
```

here's some other links which might help http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/getting_your_di

Answer (score 0):

Look into floating divs.

Have you tried googling something like "css column layout"?